# Can I batch output the graph of Secondary Structure in VMD Timeline analysis?

Tags: protein-structure, visualization

I am using the [VMD software](https://www-s.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/), and use "Extension - Analysis - Timeline - Calculate - Calc. Sec. Structure" to visualise the secondary structure of my trajectories.

1. I need to screenshot to get the graph. Can I output it using a build-in command instead?
2. I have hundreds of trajectories to analyse. Each time, I need "File - Write data file" to output the raw STRIDE code. Can I use some script to enable batch output?

Comment: Are [these](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/vmd/tutorial-html/node2.html#SECTION00025000000000000000) instructions related to your problem?

Comment: Thanks, but I do not think so. I want to "batch" output the files, as I have many trajectories to load.

Comment: Try here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/. There's way more VMD questions there.

Comment: Can I move my questions there?